# Какая часть этого кода прослушивает изменения

Tags: java, android, sms

** Я хочу написать своё событие при каждом новом sms сообщении, в какой части приложенного кода мне вставить своё событие**

public class SmsActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

```
private static SmsActivity inst;
ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView smsListView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public static SmsActivity instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);
    smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SMSList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    refreshSmsInbox();
}

public void refreshSmsInbox() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor smsInboxCursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
    int indexBody = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
    int indexAddress = smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
    if (indexBody < 0 || !smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    do {
        String str = "SMS From: " + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress) +
                "\n" + smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
        arrayAdapter.add(str);
    } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
}

public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try {
        String[] smsMessages = smsMessagesList.get(pos).split("\n");
        String address = smsMessages[0];
        String smsMessage = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; ++i) {
            smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
        }

        String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
        smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
        Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: В `updateList()`?

Comment: Отлично, сработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно отслеживать когда приходит смс. Вам тогда нужно сделать receiver.
Вот например статья по этому поводу (там в конце есть ссылка на полный проэкт):

https://m.habr.com/ru/post/149555/

Если я не правильно понял то напишите в комментариях или поправьте вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, ресивер был, просто хотел узнать  где из вышеуказанного кода вставить своё событие при получении новых sms, ваша ссылка тоже полезная